Problem installing R 4.3.3 in Ubuntu 20.04
I have the code below to install R 4.3.3 in Ubuntu 20.04. It was working fine until last week. Today, I tried to run it; however, it results in a error.
  export R_VERSION=4.3.3

  apt-get update
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    software-properties-common \
    dirmngr \
    wget
  wget -qO- https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc | \
    tee -a /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc
  add-apt-repository \
    "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"
  apt-get update
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    r-base=${R_VERSION}* \
    r-base-core=${R_VERSION}* \
    r-base-dev=${R_VERSION}* \
    r-recommended=${R_VERSION}* \
    r-base-html=${R_VERSION}* \
    r-doc-html=${R_VERSION}* \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libopenblas-dev \
    libharfbuzz-dev \
    libfribidi-dev 

I have tried multiple suggestions from the solutions on here (i.e. ask ubuntu) without success.Like installing the version directly: apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends r-base-core=4.3.3-1.2004.0. The error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '4.3.3-1.2004.0' (CRAN:20.04/focal-cran40 [all]) for 'r-base'
Selected version '4.3.3-1.2004.0' (CRAN:20.04/focal-cran40 [amd64]) for 'r-base-core'
Selected version '4.3.3-1.2004.0' (CRAN:20.04/focal-cran40 [all]) for 'r-base-dev'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 4.3.3-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
FATAL:   While performing build: while running engine: exit status 100


For me this works when installing on ubuntu 22:04:

apt -y install r-base=4.3.3* r-recommended=4.3.3*

Alas furtheron in the R install/compile process 4.4.1 is still being used
